# PHP decoding a URL

Tags: php

I have a URL that contains a department name that will pull records from the database.

The URL looks like this: `submissions.php?department=Settings,%20Security%20&%20Payments` which is the equivalent of `Settings, Security & Payments`

My query needs to pull records from the table where the department is equal to `Settings, Security & Payments`.

How can convert that GET variable back to what I would expect it to be?

I tried `html_entity_decode` but it ignores the `&` and only gave me everything prior to that.

Whats the best way to do that?

Side note, if it was my data I would make it simple and pull it by ID but we dont have a table that has ID's for the departments.

Comment: That url's badly constructed anyways. Why encode the spaces and then leave the `&` alone? Whatever code is generating that should be fixed.

Comment: Try encoding the ampersand to `%26`. PHP may be interpreting `%20Payments` as another parameter in your querystring since it does follow an ampersand. I bet if your did `print_r($_GET)` you would see an additional parameter you weren't expecting.

Comment: @MarcB that is just how the value is stored in the database. I have a filter that allows you to pull records by department and unfortunately that's how some of the departments are formatted.

Comment: fact remains, that the url's bad. if you wanted a literal & in the url, then it should be %26. Leaving is as `&` makes the browser think it's a query argument separator.

Comment: That was the point of this question.. I can do anything with the variable that getting added to the URL but I cant change the data in the database. Is there a certain way it should be encoded in the first place?

Comment: Do a urlencode on the string before it is added to the URL. Then do a urldecode when you get it on the other side. This will effectively double encode it (since it is already partially encoded in the database) and double decode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$string = "submissions.php?department=Settings,%20Security%20&%20Payments";
$decoded = urldecode($string);

echo "Original string: $string\n";
echo "Decoded string: $decoded\n";

?>
```

http://codepad.org/Bq1Gt30s

Answer (score 2):

Try urldecode()

You can see the manual here. https://www.php.net/urldecode

Comment: "The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded." It returned the same thing as entity_decode

Answer (score 0):

Use urldecode($your_URLstring)